# IIS 7.5 Custom 404 page empty when ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4 is removed and RewritePath is used

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule

I am using HTTPContext.RewritePath for a path that has no extension and does not exist on the file system.  I would like it to return my custom 404 page.  I am using IIS 7.5, .Net 4, and Integrated Pipeline on Windows 7.

The rewrite happens in an HTTPModule called RewriteExampleModule.  As shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class RewriteExampleModule : IHttpModule
{
    public RewriteExampleModule()
    {
    }

    private void context_PostAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        String path = context.Request.RawUrl;
        if (path.IndexOf("/edit/") > -1)
        {
            path = path.Replace("/edit/", "/");
            context.RewritePath(path);
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(context_PostAuthorizeRequest);
    }
}
```

It is configured in the modules section as follows,

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="RewriteExampleModule" type="RewriteExampleModule" />
</modules>
```

The result of a request to /edit/asdf where /asdf doesn't not exist is a 500 error.  It should be a 404 but it isn't.

Following,

[IIS 7.5 – a breaking change in extensionless URIs handling after Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 is applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633611/iis-7-5-a-breaking-change-in-extensionless-uris-handling-after-windows-server)

I have removed the ExtensionlessUrlHandler and now get a 404.  But, the body of the response is empty.  Together with the rewrite module shown below is my complete web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="RewriteExampleModule" type="RewriteExampleModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration a call to

/edit/asdf

where /asdf doesn't exist returns a 404 status code but no custom content as specified in web.config under httpErrors.

Why is the 404 body empty?  Any other path without the rewrite of /edit/ is fine.